# Setting working directory: Julia versus R

Tags: r, directory, julia

In `R`, starting from any working directory, I can do

```
setwd("~/Desktop")
```

and this is consistent with how my linux distribution interprets `cd` at the command line.  But `Julia` does not seem to recognize the `~/` notation:

```
julia> cd("~/Desktop")
ERROR: chdir ~/Desktop: No such file or directory
 in systemerror at error.jl:38
 in cd at file.jl:13
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: This seems to be relevant: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1136

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The idiom is just different as you can see [from the source](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/file.jl#L10).  If you invoke **cd()** without arguments, it defaults to the home directory.  The function **homedir()** can be used to prepend the home directory.

```
julia> homedir()
"/Users/jeffw"

julia> cd("/")

julia> pwd()
"/"

julia> cd()

julia> pwd()
"/Users/jeffw"
```

Combining things

```
julia> cd("$(homedir())/Desktop")

julia> pwd()
"/Users/jeffw/Desktop"
```

Comment: And if you want to change to a folder that is in the home directory? Like the OP is asking about?

Comment: `cd("$(homedir())/Desktop)` isn't portable, should be `cd(joinpath(homedir()),"Desktop"))`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Julia doesn't expand the `~`. You need to manually provide the full path. This is being worked on, but I'm on my phone right now and can't find issue.

Comment: see @Dason's comment on the original post.