# What should path be to Julia source file?

Tags: macos, julia

I have a .jl file at `/Users/myuser/Documents/JuliaLearn/Julia/mysource.jl`

In Julia Repl, I'm trying to run as:

```
include("/Users/myuser/Documents/JuliaLearn/Julia/mysource.jl")
```

But get this error:

> ERROR: could not open file
>   /Users/myuser/~/Documents/JuliaLearn/Julia/mysource.jl  in include at
>   /Applications/Julia-0.4.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
>   in include_from_node1 at
>   /Applications/Julia-0.4.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib

I also tried but get an error similar to the above:

```
include("~/Documents/JuliaLearn/Julia/mysource.jl")
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: maybe this would be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841448/setting-working-directory-julia-versus-r

Comment: @niczky12: It was. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Isomorphic to OS:

```
cd(joinpath(homedir(),"a_long","path","to_your","files"));

include("your_julia_file.jl")
```

Comment: You have to change directory in order to include a file?  Doesn't seem like a very solid solution.