# finding Julia in R

Tags: r, julia

I installed Julia 0.6.0 (release x86_64-w64-mingw32) on my acer 64 bit. Operative system: Windows 7 Home Premium (which is a [supported platform](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/README.windows.md)).
I wanted to use julia via `XRJulia`.
First, I matched R working directory and Julia homedir. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841448/setting-working-directory-julia-versus-r)

Now, I checked whether R can find Julia:

```
library(XRJulia)
findJulia(test = TRUE)
[1] FALSE
```

But it can't. What am I missing?

Comment: Where did you install `Julia`?  Is the env path set up. I just installed the package and run `findJulia(test = TRUE)#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: C:\Program Files\Julia-0.6.0

Comment: Adding the path to julia exe to the PATH variable on windows may work for you.