# XRJulia and findJulia in MacOSX

Tags: r, julia

I'm having problem in MacOSX when trying to use XRJulia package.
When I run FindJulia, I get the error:

"Error in findJulia() : 
  No julia executable in search path and JULIA_BIN environment variable not set"

There seems to be an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213269/xrjulia-and-findjulia?newreg=4b067e4e813a43bf936f971b1bcd2c00https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213269/xrjulia-and-findjulia?newreg=4b067e4e813a43bf936f971b1bcd2c00) but I don't really understand it, 
How do I add a "key" in MacOSX and how do I add Julia to the path? A step by step explanation would be very much appreciated,

Thanks

EDIT: I resolved the problem and here is the piece of code I used for setup:

> julia_setup(JULIA_HOME="/Applications/Julia-1.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin")

Comment: Hey! What Julia Package? I tried this and I got ```(v1.3) pkg> add XRJulia
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/JuliaPOMDP`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaPOMDP/Registry`
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * XRJulia (not found in project, manifest or registry)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
```

Comment: Can you also post a sample snippet of the exact commands you are trying to run so I and others can get a better idea of what’s going on?

Comment: Hello, any update on this?

Comment: Hi apologies for getting back too late. I was able to resolve the problem. 
I don't have the exact code with me but when I can I will try to post the code piece that I used to solve it

Comment: Thanks! Please add it when you can for completeness.

Comment: Here is what I used when running the julia_setup() function:

"julia_setup(JULIA_HOME="/Applications/Julia-1.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin")"