# Julia in R (JuliaCall and XRJulia not working with Julia 0.7 or newer)

Tags: r, julia

I am trying hard to make julia work through R but i am not being successful. I followed the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965747/linking-r-and-julia), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213269/xrjulia-and-findjulia) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827110/finding-julia-in-r) with no success. I added `Julia` to the path and installed and tested in `Julia` both `RCall` and `JSON` packages. I don't know what else to do T_T!

With `JuliaCall` i get the following error:

```
> julia <- julia_setup()
Julia version 0.7.0 at location C:\Users\ModellT\AppData\Local\JULIA_~1\bin will be used.
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  character argument expected
```

With `XRJulia`:

```
> findJulia()
[1] "C:\\Users\\ModellT\\AppData\\Local\\Julia_0_7\\bin\\julia.exe"
> findJulia(test = T)
[1] FALSE
```

My R and Julia version:

> R.version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64, mingw32
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          5.1
>   year           2018
>   month          07
>   day            02
>   svn rev        74947
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
>   nickname       Feather Spray
>
> julia> 
>   VERSION v"0.7.0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JuliaCall` has just finished upgrading for `Julia 0.7` and `Julia 1.0`.
The development version of `JuliaCall` should be able to support `Julia 0.7` with the latest released version of `RCall` and should be able to support `Julia 1.0` with the github master of `RCall`.

Note that the latest master of `JuliaCall` also contains a fix for segfault on Windows, which is also confirmed by a Windows user. Related discussions are at https://github.com/Non-Contradiction/JuliaCall/issues/63.

Update:
The github master of `RCall` is already released. So there should be no problem in using `JuliaCall` with `Julia 1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is that newer versions than **Julia 0.6.4** don't work with `JuliaCall` and `XRJulia` packages. They worked on my system after installing Julia 0.6.4.

Following Consistency request:

**NOTE**: I run this test with both `Julia 0.7` and `Julia 1.0`

***Julia 1.0***___________________________________________________________________________

```
trace(dyn.load, quote(print(x)))
julia_setup()

Julia version 1.0.0 at location C:\PROGRA~1\Julia\JULIA-~1.0\bin will be used. 

Tracing dyn.load(libm, DLLpath = .julia$bin_dir) on entry 
[1] "ERROR: UndefVarError: Libdl not defined" "Stacktrace:"           
[3] " [1] top-level scope at none:0"          
attr(,"status") 
[1] 1
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :   
  character argument expected 
In addition: Warning message: 
In system2(file.path(.julia$bin_dir, "julia"), shQuote(command),  :  
running command '"C:\PROGRA~1\Julia\JULIA-~1.0\bin/julia" "-e" "print(Libdl.dlpath(Base.libm_name))"' had status 1
```

`RCall` doesn't seem to work on Julia 1.0.0

```
(v1.0) pkg> build RCall
  Building Conda ───────────→ `C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\Conda\m7vem\deps\build.log`
  Building CodecZlib ───────→ `C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\CodecZlib\wwgbh\deps\build.log`
  Building SpecialFunctions → `C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\SpecialFunctions\KvXoO\deps\build.log`
  Building RCall ───────────→ `C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\RCall\OBHAc\deps\build.log`
┌ Error: Error building `RCall`:
│ ERROR: LoadError: syntax: try without catch or finally
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] include at .\boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [2] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1038
│  [3] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
│  [4] include(::String) at .\client.jl:388
│  [5] top-level scope at none:0
│ in expression starting at C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\RCall\OBHAc\deps\build.jl:24
└ @ Pkg.Operations C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:1068
```

***Julia 0.7***___________________________________________________________________________

```
> trace(dyn.load, quote(print(x)))
Tracing function "dyn.load" in package "base"
[1] "dyn.load"
> julia_setup()
Julia version 0.7.0 at location C:\PROGRA~1\Julia\JULIA-~1.0\bin will be used.
Tracing dyn.load(libm, DLLpath = .julia$bin_dir) on entry 
[1] "WARNING: C:\\PROGRA~1\\Julia\\JULIA-~1.0\\bin\\libopenlibm.DLLBase.Libdl is deprecated, run `using Libdl` instead"
[2] " in module Main"                                                                                                  
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  character argument
```

`RCall` works with Julia 0.7 but it gives some warning messages when installing in Julia

```
julia> Pkg.build("RCall")
WARNING: Base.Pkg is deprecated, run `using Pkg` instead
 in module Main
  Building CodecZlib → `C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\CodecZlib\wwgbh\deps\build.log`
  Building Conda ────→ `C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\Conda\m7vem\deps\build.log`
  Building RCall ────→ `C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\RCall\KPBrH\deps\build.log`

julia> import RCall
[ Info: Precompiling RCall [6f49c342-dc21-5d91-9882-a32aef131414]
┌ Warning: `using A.B` will only be allowed for modules, not single bindings. Use `using A: B` instead
│   caller = ip:0x0
└ @ Core :-1
WARNING: Method definition (::Type{AxisArrays.CategoricalVector{T, A} where A<:AbstractArray{T, 1} where T})(AbstractArray{T, 1}) where {T} in module AxisArrays at C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\AxisArrays\uZ7JS\src\categoricalvector.jl:43 overwritten at C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\AxisArrays\uZ7JS\src\categoricalvector.jl:47.
WARNING: Method definition (::Type{AxisArrays.CategoricalVector{T, A} where A<:AbstractArray{T, 1} where T})(AbstractArray{T, 1}) where {T} in module AxisArrays at C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\AxisArrays\uZ7JS\src\categoricalvector.jl:43 overwritten at C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\AxisArrays\uZ7JS\src\categoricalvector.jl:47.
WARNING: Method definition (::Type{AxisArrays.CategoricalVector{T, A} where A<:AbstractArray{T, 1} where T})(A<:AbstractArray{T, 1}) where {T, A<:AbstractArray{T, 1}} in module AxisArrays at C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\AxisArrays\uZ7JS\src\categoricalvector.jl:47 overwritten at C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\AxisArrays\uZ7JS\src\categoricalvector.jl:43.
WARNING: Method definition (::Type{AxisArrays.CategoricalVector{T, A} where A<:AbstractArray{T, 1} where T})(AbstractArray{T, 1}) where {T} in module AxisArrays at C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\AxisArrays\uZ7JS\src\categoricalvector.jl:43 overwritten at C:\Users\VideoLab\.julia\packages\AxisArrays\uZ7JS\src\categoricalvector.jl:47.
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'stats' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The network path was not found.

During startup - Warning message:
package 'stats' in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

**Julia 0.7** `devtools::install_github("Non-Contradiction/JuliaCall")` _________________________

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm the maintainer of `JuliaCall`. `JuliaCall` should be able to support `Julia 0.7`. I had received a similar issue report here <https://github.com/Non-Contradiction/JuliaCall/issues/63> and I'm working to solve it. But it's still unclear to me what had happened, because I don't have windows at hand. Would you follow the last post in the linked issue and try to print out more information by using `trace(dyn.load, quote(print(x)))` before `julia_setup()`?

Comment: @Consistency I run the test you asked on both `Julia 1.0` and `Julia 0.7`

Comment: Thanks! The JuliaCall master seems to fix the problem, but I'm not sure. Could you try to install JuliaCall from github using `devtools`?

Comment: Yes, `RCall` doesn't support `Julia 1.0` yet. But the maintainer is working on it at the moment. And if RCall works, then I need to test `JuliaCall` on the `Julia 1.0`. If everything goes right, then there will be a fix in a few days.

Comment: @Consistency I get the same message with the **development version**: 
`Julia version 0.7.0 at location C:\PROGRA~1\Julia\JULIA-~1.0\bin will be used.
Tracing dyn.load(libm, DLLpath = .julia$bin_dir) on entry 
[1] "WARNING: C:\\PROGRA~1\\Julia\\JULIA-~1.0\\bin\\libopenlibm.DLLBase.Libdl is deprecated, run using Libdl instead"
[2] " in module Main"                                                                                                  
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  character argument expected`

Comment: Okay. I just found that my previous fix working for julia 1.0 but not 0.7... The newest fix should work for julia 0.7. Could you give it a try?

Comment: @Consistency It makes r session abort. Check edited answer.

Comment: I have no idea what is going on, but at least the library path is correct. Maybe we could try to do `dyn.load("the dll location of libm")` in R directly. The dll location can be obtained in julia by `try using Libdl; catch; end; print(Libdl.dlpath(Base.libm_name))`.